# MiniTest Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, controller, minitest

I'm new to MiniTest. Most of the testing is easy to grasp as it is Ruby code and also has Rspec-style readability. I am, however, having trouble with authentications. As with any app, most controllers are hidden behind some sort of authentication, the most common being `authenticate_user` to ensure that a user is logged in.

How do I test a `session` -> user is logged in? I am using authentication from scratch not devise.

I do have this as a reference: https://github.com/chriskottom/minitest_cookbook_source/blob/master/minishop/test/support/session_helpers.rb

But not quite sure how to implement it.

Let's use this as an example controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

How would my test look in these basic instances?

```
test "it should GET products index" do
  # insert code to check authenticate_user
  get :index
  assert_response :success
end

test "it should GET products show" do
  # insert code to check authenticate_user
  get :show
  assert_response :success
end

#refactor so logged in only has to be defined once across controllers.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using your custom authentication methods?
If so you can pass needed session variables as a third param to request method:

```
get(:show, {'id' => "12"}, {'user_id' => 5})
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers

Otherwise, if you use any authentication library it usually provides some helper methods for testing.

Comment: What about for index pages?

Comment: I dont' see any difference `get(:index, {}, {'user_id' => 5})`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include devise test helpers and then you can use devise helpers just like in controller.

I.E:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProtectedControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  test "authenticated user should get index" do
    sign_in users(:foo)
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "not authenticated user should get redirect" do
    get :index
    assert_response :redirect
  end

end
```

Also check out this:
[How To: Test controllers with Rails 3 and 4 (and RSpec)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec))

Comment: I'm not using devise. Sorry, forgot to specify that in my post.

Comment: in rails 5 it is `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers`